# Firemonkey Camera Component is too slow

Tags: android, delphi, camera, firemonkey

I'm having an issue with `TCameraComponent` on Android.

On the first time that I run the app, the camera is ok, but if I stop the `TCameraComponent` and start it again, the camera gets too slow.

Any ideas about what is going on?

```pascal
CameraComponent1.Active := false;
CameraComponent1.Quality := FMX.Media.TVideoCaptureQuality.MediumQuality;
CameraComponent1.Kind := FMX.Media.TCameraKind.BackCamera;
CameraComponent1.FocusMode := FMX.Media.TFocusMode.ContinuousAutoFocus;
CameraComponent1.Active := True;
```

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.CameraComponent1SampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject; const ATime: TMediaTime);
begin
  CameraComponent1.SampleBufferToBitmap(imgCamera.Bitmap, True);
end;
```

Comment: The slowness of the camera is a long standing issue with Delphi, especially on Android. Please refer to: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10592

Comment: Maybe you can use the lib from https://delphiworlds.com/2020/11/native-camera-ios-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when I start the camera for the second time, it gets the high quality, so I just forced the component to change the quality and worked:

```pascal
CameraComponent1.Quality := FMX.Media.TVideoCaptureQuality.highQuality;
CameraComponent1.Quality := FMX.Media.TVideoCaptureQuality.MediumQuality;
```