# How to get multiple bitmaps from camera

Tags: android, ios, delphi, camera, firemonkey

I would like to scan a QRCode with Firemonkey in Delphi 10.4.

I can take a single photo with the code below, but I only get one `OnDidFinishTaking` event, and it's not really good to parse the final image to read the QRCode:

```
if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXCameraService, Service) then
begin
  Params.Editable := False;
  Params.NeedSaveToAlbum := True;
  Params.RequiredResolution := TSize.Create(640, 640);
  Params.OnDidFinishTaking := DoDidFinish;
  Params.OnDidCancelTaking := DoDidCancel;
  Service.TakePhoto(imgIndice, Params);
end
else
  ShowMessage('This device does not support the camera service');
```

So, I use the `TCameraComponent` instead, with the `OnSampleBufferReady` event.

That's exactly what I want, but this component is really bad, it takes a lot of time to turn on, and the image is jerky.

Does another method exist to get a fluid series of images from the camera? Like a normal QRCode scanner?

Maybe something directly from Android or iOS APIs?

Comment: https://github.com/Spelt/ZXing.Delphi

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64696779/firemonkey-camera-component-is-too-slow

Comment: I already see it and test XZing demo but they use Camera component too. When I change the quality it turn on faster but the image is jerky

Comment: Have you tried capturing video and then processing the individual frames, instead of capturing single images?

Answer (score 0):

This camera component issue has existed for a very long time.

On the android side, to get rid of the problems, you should port the Java code to Delphi.

I suggest you download the trial version here and like you did in the Delphi demo (OnSampleBufferReady) take camera image from their component.

Mobile Live Camera Publish SDK For Delphi 3.0
http://www.flashavconverter.com/content/mobile-live-camera-publish-for-delphi

so you don't have performance issues, you won't be using rtmp feature here, you'll just get the image from the camera, it will fix your problem, so even a trial will do its job.

so we looked for ways to get rid of this camera problem, it works,
flash corp regularly fixes the bugs of its components and releases the new version for the new delphi.

You can contact Flashavconverter's Service  email for assistsance.

in delphi's own component;
There is poor performance in converting raw camera pixels in delphi,

(for example, when the resolution increases, fps drops in delphi, lag starts)

you can access neon optimized codes at quality.embarcadero.com, but I have no idea how it works in delphi 11 right now.